# Verbose output missing when executing a script as CGI

Tags: output, cgi

This is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""

sshpass -p $pass ssh -v -p $port -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$ip "cd / && ls && exit"
```

It can be executed via web, or via command line.

When executed via command line I see lots of output.. including debug info from "-v" (verbose mode), etc.

But when executed via web, all I see is the listing of folders (executed command's output). No other data.

Why is the extended data missing when I execute this script via web?
Why is it there when I execute it via command line?

How can I make sure it is also there when executed via web?

Comment: Please fix your Shift key. Or learn to use it, as the case may be.

Answer (score 3):

Your "extra data" is being sent by your script to standard error, not standard output.

> why is the extended data missing when i execute this script via web ?

Because the CGI interface used between the seb server and your script only takes your script's standard *output* stream into account, not its standard *error* stream. The standard *error* is going elsewhere, possibly to the web server's error log, possibly nowhere.

> why is it there when i execute it via command line ?

Because in a terminal, standard output and standard error go by default to the same place, which is the terminal itself.

> how can i make sure it is also there when executed via web ?

You can redirect standard error to the same place as standard output:

```
exec 2>&1
```

(file descriptor 2 is standard error, file descriptor 1 is standard output.)